# Mapreduce program unable to read input file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have a small `csv` file on `hdfs` in this location: `"hdfs://csehadoop/user/department.csv"`. I use the following code in my `mapreduce` program to read the contents of the file and  store it in a `hashmap`.

```
brReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("hdfs://csehadoop/user/department.csv"));
while ((strLineRead = brReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String deptFieldArray[] = strLineRead.split(",");
        System.out.println(deptFieldArray[2].toString());
        String businessId = deptFieldArray[2].toString();
        String fields = deptFieldArray[3].toString() + "\t" + deptFieldArray[10].toString();
        DepartmentMap.put(businessId, fields);
}
```

However, the resultant `hashmap`(`DepartmentMap`) is always `null`. How can I rectify this?

Comment: what is declaration of the hashmap you used?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko private static HashMap<String, String> DepartmentMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

Comment: you are sure that `deptFieldArray[]` get good result?

Comment: Is the variable strLineRead  having any value. I mean did you get any data with Buffered reader?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read Hdfs files that way. You must open a [FSDataInputStream](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream.html) at the indicated Path. For instance:

```
Path pt = new Path("hdfs://csehadoop/user/department.csv");
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(context.getConfiguration());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(pt)));
```